# How to structure a simple PHP Exception class

Tags: php, exception

**Hi devs**

I have a simple PHP OO project. I have an exception who appears 2 times.
Something like :

```
if (!$x) {
    throw new Exception("Don't use this class here.");
}
```

I want to dev a class in order to edit this code like that :

```
if (!$x) {
    throw new ClassUsageException();
}
```

How to dev the Excpetion class with default Exception message ?

Thanks

Comment: which framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the `Exception` class

```
<?php
Class ClassUsageException extends Exception {

    public function __construct($msg = "Don't use this class here.", $code = 0) {
         parent::__construct($msg, $code); //Construct the parent thus Exception.
    }

}


try {
    throw new ClassUsageException();
} catch(ClassUsageException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage(); //Returns Don't use this class here.
}
```

Comment: I guess that the message should be already a default one, as in the question: _with default Exception message_.  So maybe in the constructor: `__construct($msg = 'the default message here', $code =0){...`. This would still allow the OP to change the message, anyway...

Comment: @FirstOne In that case, changed it.

Comment: Just note that I'm not the OP, that just my understanding of the question ^^

Comment: @FirstOne You're right, I read the question too fast, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise creating new exception classes sparsly. It is no fun to check a multitude of exceptions left and right. And if you really feel the need, check what kinds of exceptions are already defined and where in that hierarchy your exception will fit and *then* extend *that* class, i.e. give the developers a chance to catch a (meaningful) range of exceptions without having to explicitly write one catch-block after the other.

I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve here with `Don't use this class here.` but it *could* be an [InvalidArgumentException](http://docs.php.net/InvalidArgumentException)  (or something derived from that exception, if you really must). There are other mechanisms to prevent an instance of a certain class at a specific place though.